# Ошибка с типами данных

Tags: c#

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender,EventArgs e, PaintEventArgs x)
        {

            textBox2.Text = cez(textBox2.Text);
            pictureBox1.Image = picture(pictureBox1.Image, x); //здесь ошибка

        }       


     public string picture(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = textBox2.Text; 

            foreach (char c in str.ToCharArray())
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '1':
                        white(sender,e);
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        black(sender,e);
                        break;

                }
            }
            return str;
        }
     public void white(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = random.Next(0, 100); 
            int y = random.Next(0, 100);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, 1, 1);
        }


        public void black(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = random.Next(0, 100);
            int y = random.Next(0, 100);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 1, 1);
        }
```

Comment: На предыдущий ваш вопрос я давал ответ, где показано, что нужно создать Bitmap и красить его пиксели.

Comment: И не нужно создавать каждый раз экземпляр класса Random. Создайте его один раз (сделайте полем формы).

Comment: У меня не получилось реализовать то, что я хотел с помощью Bitmap, попробую ваш способ чуть позже. С random получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = picture(pictureBox1.Image, x);
```

Comment: если не сложно, объясните, пожалуйста, почему именно так?

Comment: @АнтонРябухин Хм, потому что Ваш метод `picture` возвращает строку, а не `Image`.

Comment: мне нужно рисовать в picturebox. какой тип тогда использовать?

Comment: @АнтонРябухин `System.Drawing.Image` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @АнтонРябухин Вы с кем сейчас разговариваете?